# How do I use the SHIFT-JIS encoding in Rust?

Tags: character-encoding, rust, shift-jis

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/lifthrasiir/rust-encoding/issues/18), the rust-encoding crate is missing SHIFT-JIS support. What's the best way to decode SHIFT-JIS in Rust in light of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`encoding_rs::SHIFT_JIS`](https://docs.rs/encoding_rs/0.2.4/encoding_rs/constant.SHIFT_JIS.html), a crate made for Firefox, can be used instead! :)

```
extern crate encoding_rs;
use encoding_rs::SHIFT_JIS;

fn main() {
    let data = vec![142,75,130,209,130,189,142,169,147,93,142,212,130,198,141,98,138,107,151,222];
    let (res, _enc, errors) = SHIFT_JIS.decode(&data);
    if errors {
        eprintln!("Failed");
    } else {
        println!("{}", res);
    }   
}
```

Outputs:

```
錆びた自転車と甲殻類
```

Note that `res` is a `Cow<'_, str>` - you may need to use `into_owned()` depending on your use case.