# How to get a char's unicode value?

Tags: rust

I want to get Kanji's Unicode value. It might be something looks like `let values: &[u16] = f("ののの");`

When I use `"の".as_bytes()` I got `[227, 129, 174]`.

When I use `'の'.escape_unicode()` I got `'\u306e'`, the `0x306e` is what exactly I want.

Comment: `'の' as u16`, hex encode. If you want to operate on an entire string and you’re confident that it’s all kanji, you *can* encode it as UTF-16.

Comment: ...though of course if one is looking for code points then `as u32` would be highly recommended. True that utf-16 good enough for Kanji today but in general that encoding is just a mess. Many characters will fail to give the correct code point with `u16`.

Comment: `"の".chars().map(|ch| ch as u32).collect::<Vec<_>>()`, though using `.chars()` directly should be sufficient in most cases. Note that the  needs more than 16 bits.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `char` type can be cast to `u32` using `as`.  The line

```
println!("{:x}", 'の' as u32);
```

will print "306e" (using `{:x}` to format the number as hex).

If you are sure all your characters are in the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), you can in theory also cast directly to `u16`.  For characters from supplementary planes this will silently give wrong results, though, e.g. `'' as u16` returns `0xf756` instead of the correct `0x1f756`, so you need a strong reason to do this.

Internally, a `char` is stored as a 32-bit number, so `c as u32` for some character `c` only reinterprets the memory representation of the character as an `u32`.

Comment: I'd go as far as to say "don't EVER use `u16` at all!" It's just misleading and an unncessary "optimization." But kudos for working out and showing that the `as u16` silently drops off the higher-order 16 bits of the code point. That's good information to have and nicely researched. I'd suggest phrasing it more as "Don't do this" because you might know your characters are all in the BMP today, but tomorrow they might not be.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, do you know how to get its Shift JIS value? Should I use a lookup table?

Comment: @RayToal I agree and changed the wording slightly.

Comment: @AurevoirXavier I just googled that for you – here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136939/how-do-i-use-the-shift-jis-encoding-in-rust