# How to get UTF-8 index of char in Rust

Tags: utf-8, rust, char

I'm very new to rust.
How I can to get UTF-8 index of char symbol in Rust.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) you have a reference to utf table.

```rust
let bracket = '[';

fn get_utf(c:&[u8])->&str{
  // don't know how to obtain utf index
}

let result = get_utf(bracket); // 005B
```

I tried [this function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.encode_utf8), but it does not work in a way I expect.

[This](https://docs.rs/encoding/0.2.33/encoding/) crate might be useful, but I don't know how to use it.

Sorry, not much of my effort.

Comment: UTF-8 is a variable length multi-byte encoding for all symbols ("code points") of all scripts in Unicode, a numbering of code points. For 7bits UTF-8 == ASCII, single byte, and '[' casted to int is 0x5B == 91.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html) in Rust represents a [Unicode scalar value](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value). You can use `as` to cast it to a `u32`:

```
let bracket = '[';
let result = bracket as u32;

println!("{:04X}", result); // prints "005B"
```

See also: [How to get a char's unicode value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919531/how-to-get-a-chars-unicode-value)

Comment: Since OP is new to Rust and wants to assign value into a variable, this might support the answer : `let result = format!("{:04X}", bracket as u32);`

Comment: I edited it to be a little more explicit. Its not clear to me what OP wants to use it for, so I don't know whether it should be an integer or a string. But I hope the example helps regardless.